# Implement oauth2 in to existing sprig boot application

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot application that i need to integrate OAuth2 into. This means running both a resource and Authorization Server. Currently i am using Java config and have a customer UserDetails Object and service along with a relatively standered WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I want to allow current user to long in restfully using OAuth2. Unfortunately i need to do this but cant get it to work.
Thanks

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried?  Where is the code and the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [tutorial article](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/02/01/spring-cloud-security-with-oauth2/) exactly about that topic earlier this year. This describes, how you can build a entire setup with pure spring-oauth2 without spring-cloud.

This describes why you integrate both, and how to do it. If you are looking for a more advance solution, you may look at [JHipster UAA](http://jhipster.github.io/using-uaa/), which implements spring-cloud-security in a more detailed setup for microservice architectur. You can review my [JHipster UAA setup](https://github.com/xetys/jhipster-uaa-setup), to look how the corresponding resource servers are configured, to use spring-cloud-security in combination with oauth2 authorized feign clients, next to plain password to JWT token exchange.